# It is possible to give list-style-type for some elements of <li> and for others dont?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of answers. And I have inside each list item `<li>` the number of the answer, a paragraph ("test..."), and two links.

And I want to have a `list-style-type: circle;` in my links. But my links aren´t `<li>` elements, they are inside a `<li>` element.

Do you know if it is possible do something like this?

I have my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9ww2qpd/1/

[image]

Comment: can you use css3 in your implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So just make them `<li>` elements. For example:

```
<h4>Answer 1</h4>
<p> test  test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest  testtest test  test test</p>
<span>Saber mais:</span><br/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can nest ordered/unordered lists to whatever depth you want. Then apply the CSS style as desired to the list.

Answer (score 4):

Without changing the HTML, you could always use the [`:before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), along with the escaped `content` value `'\2022'`. Just change the `font-size` of the element accordingly.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Lw9ebd/)

```
#answers ul li a:before {
    content:'\2022';
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using CSS3 pseudo elements instead of a nested `ul` `li` implementation, you could use `:before` to create the "bullet". This will also give you more control over the visual style and position of the bullet.

```
#answers ul li a{padding-left:30px; position:relative;}
#answers ul li a:before{content:" "; position:absolute; top:50%; left:24px; border-radius: 100%; background: black; height:4px; width:4px; margin:-4px;}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ww2qpd/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want or need to do this without changing the HTML markup, set the `display` property to `list-item` for the elements that you wish to display as items of a bulleted list and prevent the effect of the `<br/>` tags. Example:

```
#answers a { display: list-item;  }
#answers br { display: none; }
```

Note that these affect all `a` and `br` elements inside the block with `id="answers"`. It is not clear whether this is desired.

The point is that `list-style-type` just sets the style of the bullet or other marker, if one is used. It does not cause the marker to appear. Or, in other words, that property affects only elements that have `display: list-item`.

Better, if you can change the markup, just use `<ul>` and `<li>` markup for elements that you want to display as a bulleted list.

Answer (score 1):

### SOLUTION 1

To make your links both (1) look like a list item and (2) behave like a list item, you should set the `display`, `list-style-type` and `list-style-position` attributes of that element.

You should also remove the `<br />` elements behind of your list items.

**EXAMPLE CODE :**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#answers{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#answers ul{
    list-style:none;
}

#answers ul li{
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#answers ul li a{
    display: list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: circle;
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Answer 1</h4>
            <p> test  test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest  testtest test  test test</p>
            <span>Saber mais:</span><br/>
            <a href="#">Who are we?</a>
            <a href="#">Who are we?</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**THE FIDDLE :**

**http://jsfiddle.net/x9ww2qpd/5/**

---

### SOLUTION 2

As an alternative to solution 1, you can just wrap your a elements in list elements.

Here, you should also remove the `<br />` elements behind of your list items & add some additional styling for list within lists.

**EXAMPLE CODE :**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#answers{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#answers ul{
    list-style:none;
}

#answers ul li{
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#answers ul ul{
    list-style:circle;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

#answers ul ul li{
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="answers">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Answer 1</h4>
            <p> test  test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest  testtest test  test test</p>
            <span>Saber mais:</span><br/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**THE FIDDLE :**

**http://jsfiddle.net/x9ww2qpd/6/**